# Set Accessor in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

Is this a true statement?

the Set accessor never gets called unless someone sets the .Net property in procedural code. When setting the property in XAML, data binding to it, and so on, WPF calls SetValue directly

(or may be is an old statement)

Thanks

Comment: It'd be pretty simple to whip up a sample app to find out.

Comment: This applies only to DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is true, yes.  If you want to do something when a property is changed, use the `OnPropertyChanged` event:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.onpropertychanged.aspx